# odata ApiController.User == NULL after upgrade to web api 5.0.0-rc1

Tags: webforms, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I'm using Windows Auth and it was working fine on this odata controller.  But after I got the latest NuGet package (prerelease 5.0.0-rc1) something changed and `ApiController.User` is null.  It's not passing the Windows Auth anymore.  Any ideas?  I tried adding the [Authorize] attribute but that didn't work - maybe that needs more config somewhere else.

```
public class ProductsController : EntitySetController<Product, int>
{
protected ProjectContextUnitOfWork UoW;
protected UserRepository UserRepo;
protected ProductRepository ProductRepo;
protected Project.Models.User CurrentUser;

// odata/Products/

public ProductsController()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage msg = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "User not authenticated.");
        throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
    }

    ProjectUserPrincipal LoggedInUser = this.User as ProjectUserPrincipal;


    // - closed in Dispose()
    UoW = new ProjectContextUnitOfWork(false); //without lazy loading

    UserRepo = new UserRepository(UoW);
    ProductRepo = new ProductRepository(UoW);

    CurrentUser = UserRepo.Get(LoggedInUser.Username, LoggedInUser.Domain);
}

protected override Product GetEntityByKey(int id)
{
    var x = from b in ProductRepo.GetAvailableProductsWithNumbers(CurrentUser)
            where b.Id == id
            select b;

    return x.FirstOrDefault();
}

...
}
```

Other details:

- .NET 4.5
- Web Forms

Also, when I reverted back to 5.0.0.beta2, without any other changes, it works again.  So it's definitely a change in `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi`.  I'm ok with making code changes, I just need some tips.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using the ApiController.User in controller constructor. At that time, the property has not been initialized. You should:

- Add [Authorize] attribute on your controller
- Move the initialization code in Initialize method

So the code looks like:

```
[Authorize]
public class ProductsController : EntitySetController<Product, int>
{
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        ProjectUserPrincipal LoggedInUser = this.User as ProjectUserPrincipal;


        // - closed in Dispose()
        UoW = new ProjectContextUnitOfWork(false); //without lazy loading

        UserRepo = new UserRepository(UoW);
        ProductRepo = new ProductRepository(UoW);

        CurrentUser = UserRepo.Get(LoggedInUser.Username, LoggedInUser.Domain);
    }
}
```